# Exchange 2010 CAS and MB server

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, cas

In exchange 2010, can a CAS server from AD site A connect to a MB server on AD site B? Or it both of them have to be in the same AD site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CAS server has to exist in each AD site that has a mailbox server.  Common with DAG though the mailbox itself might move between MB servers that are in different AD Sites.

I'm not really getting your question though.  Like Technet says, "When the Client Access server receives a user connection request, it queries Active Directory to determine which Mailbox server is hosting the user's mailbox. The Client Access server then retrieves the Active Directory site membership of that Mailbox server and proxies the connection to the Mailbox server."

If you are referring to a simple setup with a single CAS server and single MB server, then yeah I guess they do have to be in the same AD site since you have to have at least one CAS server in the site that holds a MB server.

Comment: Well right now i have 2 servers with all roles in 2 AD sites, DAG between the 2.
User1 in site1 has its mailbox on db1 is active on server2 in site2. The rpcclientaccessserver is set to server1 in site1.
Result, outlook will not connect.
If i switch the active db1 to server1, outlook will connect.

Comment: You should have included this in your OP, it's important to the question and actually sheds light on a real issue.  You need to read this: http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2012/05/30/rpc-client-access-cross-site-connectivity-changes.aspx and understand CAS Arrays, RPCclientaccessserver failover, the settings available to you based on your version of 2010, etc.

Comment: I just finished reading your article. Very interesting.
I'm on Exchange 2010 sp3. The default value for AllowCrossSiteRPCClientAccess is false, so according to the article, when i switch DB1 to be active on server2, outlook should change its CAS server to CAS server2 which connect to MB server2.

But i then dont understand the usage of RPCClientAccessServer...

Comment: That is correct, with Outlook prompting to be restarted.  It is easily tested by moving a mailbox from one mailbox server in one AD site to another MB server in another AD site if you'd like.  But this isn't quite the same as actual DAG failover where the actual database fails over and not just a single mailbox "move".

Comment: Reread the `Cross-Site Database *over Events` part near the bottom.  Including `Note that the RPCClientAccessServer property is not updated as that defines the preferred site.` and `Like in the move mailbox scenario, the WrongServer ROP forces the Outlook client to do a profile discovery and update the profile based on new information found within the directory. The profile gets updated and once the client is restarted, the client establishes its connections to the new RPC endpoint.` - so in your case Outlook should have prompted for a restart and connected to the right CAS.